# BeautifulSoup not returning .text in csv and extra unwanted numbers

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scraper

I have this code

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

f = csv.writer(open('destinations.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Destinations', 'Country'])

pages = []

for i in range(1, 3):
   url = 'http://www.travelindicator.com/destinations?page=' + str(i)
   pages.append(url.decode('utf-8'))

for item in pages:
   page = requests.get(item, sleep(2))
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content.text, 'lxml')
   for destinations_list in soup.select('.news-a header'):
       destination = soup.select('h2 a')
       country = soup.select('p a')

       print (destinations_list.text)

       f.writerow([destinations_list])
```

which gives me the console answer of:

```
Ellora
1

3/5
India



Volterra
2
2/5
Italy


Hamilton
3
3/5
New Zealand



London
4
5/5
United Kingdom


Sun Moon Lake
5

5/5
Taiwan



Texel
6
```

etc...

Firstly I am unsure why the extra numbers are being added as I have only specified the parts I want for each country.

Secondly, when I try and format it into a CSV file, it doesn't remove the HTML even though I have specified my soup to give me content.text. Been trying to figure it out for an hour and am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

```
pages = []
destinations_list = []
country = []   

 for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

    temp =  soup.findAll('article')
    for l in temp:
        destinations_list.append(l.find('h2').text)
        country = l.find('p')
        country.append(country.find('a').text)

print destinations_list
print country
```

Output:

```
Ellora
India

Volterra
Italy
Hamilton
New Zealand

London
United Kingdom
Sun Moon Lake
Taiwan

Texel
The Netherlands
Zhengzhou
China

Vladivostok
Russia
Charleston
United States

Banska Bystrica
Slovakia

Lviv
Ukraine

Viareggio
Italy
Wakkanai
Japan

Nordkapp
Norway
Jericoacoara
Brazil

Tainan
Taiwan

Boston
United States

Keelung
Taiwan

Stockholm
Sweden

Shaoxing
China

Bohol
Distance to you
Bohol
Philippines

Saint Petersburg
Russia
Malmo
Sweden

Elba
Italy
Gdansk
Poland

Langkawi
Malaysia

Poznan
Poland

Daegu
South Korea
Abu Simbel
Egypt

Melbourne
Australia

Reunion
Reunion
Annecy
France

Colombo
Sri Lanka

Penghu
Taiwan

Conwy
United Kingdom
Monterrico
Guatemala

Janakpur
Nepal

Bimini
Bahamas

Lake Tahoe
United States

Essaouira
Morocco
```

Comment: Hi, could you give a bit more detail as to what this is doing? Currently destination_list isn't being used in your example above

Comment: @EikHunter I have added the code where I have declared the lists. I tried to find the <article> tag and from which i found the destination and its respective country using <h2> and <p> tags

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly, besides all I want to do is amend the script I currently have so that it spits out text without the html tags and stores it in a csv

Comment: You are printing the text from `'.news-a header'` tag that's why you are seeing those numbers in your output; if you want to parse them you have to use the respective tags to scrap the country and destination